# A word meaning "you do what you have to do"?

Tags: word-request

Does anyone know such a word? (Not something like 'to adhere to', 'to live up to' or 'to accomplish'.) It has to be a word that can be used on its own.

Comment: Are you looking for *obligated* / *commited*?

Comment: I was **compelled** to write this.

Comment: It's unclear to me what sense you're after. I'm also not sure whether by "a word that can be used on its own" you mean a single-word request or you want an intransitive verb. For what it's worth, the first two words came to mind are *comply* and *accede*.

Comment: What @Damkerng said. Without a precise context in which to use the target word, we're just taking potshots in the dark. Here's mine: **comply**.

Comment: It might help us find the right word if you added an example of how you would like to use the word.

Comment: Note that "do what you have to do" could be meant literally -- you meet your obligations or obey orders. It is also an idiom used to indicate that you don't like the decision that a person is making but you have given up arguing. "I'm going to quit!" "I think it would be foolish to quit your job over such a minor issue." "No, I'm just fed up." "Well, you do what you have to do."

Comment: Obligated to what? Commited what? Compelled to write this =/= doing what you have to do (you didn't have to do it).  To comply with what? To accede to what?

None of these words specifically mean you do what you have to do.

Comment: I understand that you ultimately want to use the word on its own, but we need more detail about the situation and the intended communication in order to figure out which word is going to fit. Please [edit your question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/39800/edit) so that it meets [the level of detail that works for this format](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and can be answered the way that you want it to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the word you're after is [**obliged**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obliged):

> You are **obliged** to raise your children because it's something you have to do as a father.